# QThreadPool performance

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, threadpool

Why my quick sort with 4 thread work slower then with 1 thread?
Which benefits will give algorithm using  MPI?
for n = 10000000;
Time normal: 1.22s
Time thread count 4: 1.66s

main.cpp http://pastebin.com/eiqKraHB
header http://pastebin.com/mkn3wyfZ

```
#include "quicksorttask.h"

#include <QThreadPool>
#include <QDebug>

QuickSortTask::QuickSortTask(int arr[], int left, int right):
    mArr{arr},
    mLeft{left},
    mRight{right}
{
}

void QuickSortTask::run()
{
    int i = mLeft, j = mRight;
    int pivot = mArr[(mLeft + mRight) / 2];

    int tmp;
    /* partition */
    while (i <= j)
    {
        while (mArr[i] < pivot)
        {
            i++;
        }
        while (mArr[j] > pivot)
        {
            j--;
        }
        if (i <= j)
        {
            tmp = mArr[i];
            mArr[i] = mArr[j];
            mArr[j] = tmp;
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    };

    /* recursion */
    if (mLeft < j)
    {
        if (abs(mLeft - j) > 100000)
        {
            QuickSortTask *task = new QuickSortTask(mArr, mLeft, j);
            QThreadPool::globalInstance()->start(task);
        }
        else
        {
            quickSort(mArr, mLeft, j);
        }
    }
    if (i < mRight)
    {
        if (abs(i - mRight) > 100000)
        {
            QuickSortTask *task = new QuickSortTask(mArr, i, mRight);
            QThreadPool::globalInstance()->start(task);
        }
        else
        {
            quickSort(mArr, i, mRight);
        }
    }
}

void QuickSortTask::quickSort(int arr[], int left, int right) {
    int i = left, j = right;
    int tmp;
    int pivot = arr[(left + right) / 2];

    /* partition */
    while (i <= j) {
        while (arr[i] < pivot)
            i++;
        while (arr[j] > pivot)
            j--;
        if (i <= j) {
            tmp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = tmp;
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    };

    /* recursion */
    if (left < j)
        quickSort(arr, left, j);
    if (i < right)
        quickSort(arr, i, right);
}
```

Comment: Multithreading is very expensive. It's not surprising that you feel its price.

Comment: How to get benefits  then?

Comment: Do you think there's a magic "make life better" button that you can just press and speed everything up? And you think nobody else would want to do that? No such luck. You need to analyze your situation carefully and identify opportunities for taking advantage of parallelism and concurrency very carefully, and then design your program accordingly.